# C# WPF accordion collapsing Images

Tags: c#, wpf, image, user-interface, accordion

I've decided to took up a evening time project. I decided to write a simple GUI application displaying info about units form some game.
I've poked around and decided to do it in a C# WPF application. I have a background in java and C, so programming isn't that different.

I want to add some eye candy to it by having a series of images cropped to half one under another. And when one gets a mouse click I want to show it whole. (ie accordion behaviour), if some picture is already fullsize I want to collapse it.

I was thinking about couple of solutions, but since its my first C# project I thought it best to ask for the best/easiest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [Customizing WPF Expander with ControlTemplate](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ExpanderTemplateArticle.aspx) article over on codeproject.com...

Comment: oh wow thats exactly what I was looking for, great tutorial. Thanks you saved me a lot of time :D

Comment: np, bookmarked that one recently so it was fresh in memory... glad it was helpful...

Answer (score 2):

I think the WPF Expander control is what you are looking for. You can use a StackPanel to create a series of them.